# Nautilus menu too small after upgrade to 18.10

Tags: upgrade, nautilus

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 from 18.04, and now the Nautilus menu is too small to fit all the menu items (See in the screenshot below). The menu item "显示隐藏文件" (which is simplified Chinese for "show hidden files") is cut off and is very hard to focus on right now.

[image: Screenshot showing broken menu]

Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

Comment: seems that it depends on the `nautilus` window dimensions..https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmgkn.gif